# Reference request for the evolution of faces

Tags: evolution, literature

We humans have faces, as well as many other animals, like cats, dogs, monkeys, etc. But there was a time on planet Earth before there were any faces in living things. I am currently very interested in how faces evolved. Is there any book or paper on this topic? I would like some references.

Comment: What is and isn't a face? Do mice not have faces? What about a crocodile? A fish? A fruit fly? If any of those do not have a face, what makes what they do have not a face?

Comment: To expand on Bryan's question: how is it different from the evolution of _heads_?

Comment: @MaximilianPress A head of lettuce, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you are interested in is really the evolution of *heads* (which I think imply faces), then [cephalization](https://This%20is%20called%20%5Bcephalization%5D(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalization)%20and%20is%20somewhat%20well%20studied.) is what you are looking for.

Namely, when bilaterally symmetric organisms colocalize sensory organs, feeding apparatus, nervous system, and in most cases a brain.

[image: Phylogeny depicting the inferred step of cephalization in animal evolution]
Fig 1: Wikipedia's figure showing where cephalization occurred.

Note that starfish and other echinoderms lost their ancestral cephalized state and went back to radially symmetric headless animals!

Comment: Interesting article in Nature: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06669-2 "This finding suggests that from the perspective of ectoderm patterning, **echinoderms are mostly head-like animals** and provides a developmental rationale for the re-evaluation of the events that led to the evolution of the derived adult body plan of echinoderms." - perhaps they're more bodyless than headless!

Comment: @BryanKrause woah. biology is weird!

Comment: @MaximilianPress Perhaps you are the one who is weird, he who has a strange body hanging off its head.